# Reputation losses aren't reflected in the API

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, reputation

This includes reputation recalculations (e.g., [the latest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/85974/how-about-a-message-letting-us-know-the-reason-for-large-changes-to-our-rep/85988#85988)) and (speculative) when people take upvote back.

First case you can see on standard [stackauth/users query](http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/7815534d-2e9a-47cc-ab67-ef27e377b5af/associated): it displays meta reputation before recalculation.

Second case is my assumption: yesterday for several hours query ascribed to me 10 points more than site actually shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine to me now.

There were a few bugs handled recently in our "network wide" user tracking, which has taken over supplying reputation numbers for the StackAuth methods.